# CMake is not able to find BOOST libraries

Tags: c++, bash, boost, cmake

I tried everything like:

1. Configure environment variable
2. Make fresh build
3. Re-install BOOST from source
4. `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

But still getting following Errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 (message):
 Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

 Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
 directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
 Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMakeLists.txt:147 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
Boost's headers.
```

Source code directory for boost: `/usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0`
Boost Library path: `/usr/local/lib`
Boost Header file: `/usr/local/include/boost`

Here is `bashrc file`:

```
BOOST_ROOT="/usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0"
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS="/usr/local/lib"
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR="/usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0"
```

How to solve these Errors? Am i missing something?

## Edit:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDTOOLCHAIN -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0 -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/usr/local/include/boost -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/usr/local/lib -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/python2.7 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/python2.7 -DCMA-DRDK_BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPERS=
```

Comment: Can you show the output of CMake if you do `cmake . -DBoost_DEBUG=ON`?

Comment: @Fraser :http://pastebin.com/cPRNegEi 
BTW my boost version is 1_45_0

Comment: Looks like it's not picking up the environment variables.  See lines 8-10 of your output.  You can try passing these as CMake variables.  Maybe even just BOOST_ROOT would be enough: `cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local`

Comment: @Fraser: Would it be `cmake . -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0` ?

Tried and got the same Error :(

Comment: Did you build Boost from source in /usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0?  Does CMake's debug output at least now show that it's looking in /usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0 ?

Comment: Yes, I build it from given directory 
Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/caQiBRcv

Comment: So you have a file /usr/local/src/boost_1_45_0/boost/version.hpp ?

Comment: Yes, and here is the content: http://pastebin.com/ZSHRxMch

Comment: This could be a permissions thing then.  Can you access these without sudo?

Comment: @Fraser: Check the updated Edit section in question. After running this command i got this:
http://pastebin.com/LakszjG2

Comment: Looks like Boost is now found then.  The python errors should probably be a new question, but I'd expect if you do `sudo apt-get install libpython-dev` then CMake would find them automatically.  Not sure how cross-compiling affects this.  Was the Boost thing a permission issue then?

Comment: @Fraser: It's already installed..No, It was not a permission issue. WOuld it be any alternative for python? What if i want to disable it?

Comment: Be good to know what the Boost problem was.  As for Python while cross-compiling, I can't really help too much.  It looks like you can disable CMake trying to find Python by editing the CMakeLIsts.txt file around line 114, but if they've made it required, probably it's being used unconditionally somewhere else, and you'll then just get a failure at that point.  Like I said, probably time for a new question :-)

Comment: @AmitPal Please add an answer yourself instead of editing the answer into your question, that way people can see that the question is answered.

Comment: @AmitPal - Did that last line under EDIT fix the problem?  If, YES, then answer your own question so people will the the question is answered, as Andreas Haferburg said in his comment above.

Comment: Try adding `-DBoost_DEBUG=TRUE` to your `cmake` command line to see where the `FindBoost` macro is searching.

Comment: Some versions of Boost use the flag `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and others use the flag `Boost_INCLUDEDIR` (**without the underscore**). You can check the right one for your case by reading the `FindBoost.cmake` file, under `path-to-cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake`

Comment: @AmitPal Could you answer Andreas and Patricia 's question ?

Answer (score 58):

Try to complete cmake process with following libs:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

Comment: For me libboost-all-dev was missing and it helped.

Comment: Me as well the `libboost-all-dev` package solved the `-- Could NOT find Boost` Cmake issue to search for boost system wide.

Answer (score 17):

I'm using this to set up boost from cmake in my `CMakeLists.txt`. Try something similar (make sure to update paths to your installation of boost).

```
SET (BOOST_ROOT "/opt/boost/boost_1_57_0")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.57.0/include")
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.57.0/lib")

SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.55.0")
set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= 1.55) required.")
else()
  message(STATUS "Setting up BOOST")
  message(STATUS " Includes - ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS " Library  - ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (NOT Boost_FOUND)
```

This will either search default paths (`/usr`, `/usr/local`) or the path provided through the cmake variables (`BOOST_ROOT`, `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`). It works for me on cmake > 2.6.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error the first time I wanted to install LightGBM on python (GPU version).

You can simply fix it with this command line :

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

the boost libraries will be installed and you'll be fine to continue your installation process.

Comment: For me installing libboost-all-dev fix the proble,

Answer (score 1):

seems the answer is in the comments and as an edit but to clarify this should work for you:

```
export BUILDDIR='your path to  build directory here'
export SRCDIR='your path to source dir here'
export BOOST_ROOT="/opt/boost/boost_1_57_0"
export BOOST_INCLUDE="/opt/boost/boost-1.57.0/include"
export BOOST_LIBDIR="/opt/boost/boost-1.57.0/lib"
export BOOST_OPTS="-DBOOST_ROOT=${BOOST_ROOT} -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=${BOOST_INCLUDE} -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=${BOOST_LIBDIR}"
(cd ${BUILDDIR} && cmake ${BOOST_OPTS} ${SRCDIR})
```

you need to specify the arguments as command line arguments or you can use a toolchain file for that, but cmake will not touch your environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that the FindBoost macro might be looking for an earlier version, for instance, 1.58.0 when you might have 1.60.0 installed.  I suggest popping open the FindBoost macro from whatever it is you are attempting to build, and checking if that's the case.  You can simply edit it to include your particular version.  (This was my problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Paul-g for your advise. For my part it was a bit different.

I installed Boost by following the Step 5 of : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

And then I add PATH directory in the "FindBoos.cmake", located in /usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules :

> ```
> SET (BOOST_ROOT "../boost_1_60_0")
> SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "../boost_1_60_0/boost")
> SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "../boost_1_60_0/libs")
>
> SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.55.0")
> set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Long answer to short, if you install boost in custom path, all header files must in ${path}/boost/.

if you want to konw why cmake can't find the requested Boost libraries after you have set `BOOST_ROOT/BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, you can check `cmake install location path_to_cmake/share/cmake-xxx/Modules/FindBoost`.

cmake which will find `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` in `boost/config.hpp` in `BOOST_ROOT`. That means your boost header file must in `${path}/boost/`, any other format (such as `${path}/boost-x.y.z`) will not be suitable for `find_package` in CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue inside an alpine docker container, my solution was to add the boost-dev apk library because libboost-dev was not available.