# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.

Tags: macos, vim, makefile, cmake, youcompleteme

I try to generated makefile file.
I use

```
cmake -G " Unix Makefiles" ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cp
```

It gives me the following result:

```
Using libclang to provide semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC
CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  ycm/CMakeLists.txt:217 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1842 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ycm/CMakeLists.txt:217 (find_package)


Using external libclang: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libclang.dylib
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/gtest
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/gtest
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/gtest
   used as include directory in directory /Users/shitfly/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/tests/gmock/gtest

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/shitfly/ycm_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I think I already has installed YCM in Vendle in `~ / .vim / bundle / YouCompleteMe`,but maybe not,How do i check it?

I checked my directory and I already have these directory in Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)

How do I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake is not able to find BOOST libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173330/cmake-is-not-able-to-find-boost-libraries)

Comment: The first and **main error** in the configure log is about finding Boost. There are many questions about such problems, so check them first. If they do not help, provide information about your Boost installation.